# which event will fire off fastest and most consistently - matchMedia, window.resize, orientationchange or both?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile, webkit

Basically I need to fire off a function when a user rotates their handset and would like to know in everyones experience which event they would best recommend for this so that the function gets called fastest and most consistently. I understand that all the events mentioned in my title have their positives and negatives on various webkit devices so would like to make sure I'm using the correct method.

Im also predominantly testing on iOS and Android v2.2+ devices

All advise appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found orientationchange to be pretty reliable on both Android (native browser) and iOS.